# Linux - listing and removing multiple different files which have names containing specific pattern

Tags: linux, files

I have multiple folders which contains files and folders created with Windows File History. The filenames all have the same structure e.g - `Super secret document (YYYY_MM_DD HH_MM_SS UTC).ext`

For example *Documents* folder looks like this:

```
...
Default (2020_10_28 06_34_32 UTC).rdp
Default (2020_10_29 06_43_49 UTC).rdp
Default (2020_11_02 06_45_18 UTC).rdp
desktop (2019_10_03 12_32_29 UTC).ini
desktop (2019_11_13 10_57_26 UTC).ini
desktop (2019_12_11 16_12_56 UTC).ini
...
Copy of 2019 (2019_08_03 12_32_29 UTC).xlsx'
Copy of 2019 (2019_10_03 12_32_29 UTC).xlsx'
VW (2020_09_08 12_12_20 UTC).docx
VW (2020_09_08 14_27_50 UTC).docx
Min20071007510 (2020_07_10 05_56_02 UTC).pdf
Min20071007510 (2020_07_11 05_56_02 UTC).pdf
...
```

By using this command via `find` I could filter in the files with the specified structure:

```
find * -type f -name "*\ (*_*_*\ *_*_*\ UTC).*"
```

I am trying to **remove** all individual files apart from latest copy of each file and I am out of ideas how can I do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Are files of the same type always in the same directory or are e.g. "desktop"-files in different directories? Are suffixed for same beginnings always the same or are there e.g. "desktop ... .ini" **and** "desktop ... .rdp" files? Or do you want to do the selection **within** each directory **separately**?

Comment: To clarify this issue, the files are with different filenames and extensions (as they are backups from a workstation). The only common thing is that the file have a fixed timestamp structure, as mentioned in the first post.

For example Documents folder has the following files:

`...
Copy of 2019 (2019_08_03 12_32_29 UTC).xlsx'
Copy of 2019 (2019_10_03 12_32_29 UTC).xlsx'
VW (2020_09_08 12_12_20 UTC).docx
VW (2020_09_08 14_27_50 UTC).docx
Min20071007510 (2020_07_10 05_56_02 UTC).pdf
Min20071007510 (2020_07_11 05_56_02 UTC).pdf
....
`
and many more.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of files
files=$(find . name "*.dat" | sort -r)

lastfile=""
IFS=$'\n'
for filename in $files
do
        parts=( $(grep -Eo '.* |\(.*\)' <<< "$filename") )

        # Get the first part of the file name
        filepart="${parts[0]}"

        # If this is a new set of files, this is the file kept.
        if [ "$filepart" != "$lastfile" ]
        then
                echo "Keeping $filename"
        else
                echo "Removing $filename"
                rm $filename
        fi
        lastfile=$filepart
done
```

Using a two-step process here.

First, we get a list of all the files.  That is the `find` command.  You will want to modify the pattern for you file set which might just be `find /path/` if you want to select a directory of files.  That list is sorted in reverse.  This allows the pattern with the most recent (newest) date to be first.

Now that we have the list, we want to loop through it.  We'll keep the first file any time the first part of the file name matches.  `grep` will break the file name into two parts: the name, and the date code.  It expects the name will be separated with a space, and the date code to be in parentheses. That will make up the variable `parts`.  Comparing the first part of the file with the last will tell you if you are on a new set of data or not.  Remember: the list is sorted so this only happens if the first part of the file name has changed.

There may be more eloquent solutions for which others can add comments--I am a functional at `bash` script but by no means a master.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my question with the help of ChatGPT (I know, I am lazy)

Here is the script which recursively goes through Windows File History based backup and deletes all file copies except the latest copy:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A latest_files

# Find all files in the current directory and its subdirectories
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    # Check if the file has a date in the format (YYYY_MM_DD HH_mm_ss UTC)
    if [[ $file =~ \(([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2} UTC)\) ]]; then
        date_match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        # Extract the base filename (excluding the date and extension)
        base_filename="${file%% (*}.${file##*.}"

        # If the date is greater than the stored date for the same full filename or if the filename is not stored
        if [[ "${latest_files[$file]}" < "$date_match" || -z "${latest_files[$file]}" ]]; then
            # Keep the latest version of the file
            latest_files["$file"]="$date_match"

            # Remove the older versions with the same full filename
            for old_file in "${!latest_files[@]}"; do
                if [[ "$old_file" != "$file" && "${old_file%% (*}" == "${file%% (*}" && "${latest_files[$old_file]}" != "$date_match" ]]; then
                    rm -f "$old_file"
                fi
            done
        else
            # Remove this version as it's older
            rm -f "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions with the **find** command.
For your particular case the command would be something like:
`find /path/to/backup/ -type f -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '.*_backup_[0-9]+\.ext' -delete`

Hope it serves!

Comment: Please note that OP wants to keep the latest version!

Comment: As @FelixJN mentioned I want to delete all versions of the file _except_ the latest one.

Comment: I modified my answer to adapt it!

Comment: I might be missing something, but that still doesn't keep the latest file, does it?